# LD_LIBRARY_PATH cannot be seen in python os.environ

Tags: python

Have a problem with LD_LIBRARY_PATH in python. I can't get it in python interpreter. I'm using python:

```
$ Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jul 22 2015, 16:47:47)[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)] on linux2

>>> import os
>>> print os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH']
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/UserDict.py", line 22, in __getitem__
raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'
```

But in the shell, the LD_LIBRARY_PATH has value:

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/var/test/lib
```

don't know why the LD_LIBRARY_PATH is ignored ?

When I do a manually export of a test variable 'MY_TEST', I can see it

```
$exprot MY_TEST=/var/
>>> print os.environ['MY_TEST']
/var/
```

But if I export the LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

```
    $export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/var
     >>> print os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH']
     Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
     File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/UserDict.py", line 22, in __getitem__
     raise KeyError(key)
     KeyError: 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'
```

does anybody know why?

Comment: Found that the selinux bit is set for the python executable, then the "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" will be ignored

Answer (score 0):

Linux will "sanitise" certain things in the environment when an `exec` of another program results in a change that could be problematic (in a security context). *One* of these problematic things is the library path since it could otherwise be used as an possible attack vector, such as:

- Find any executable owned by `root` with the `setuid` bit set.
- Find out what shared libraries (and functions within them) were used. Let's say it's `printf`, for example.
- Create a shared library containing a `printf` function that opens up a terminal/shell in a separate process, then just waits for it to exit.
- Change `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` so that the location of your library is the first thing on it.
- Run the privileged executable.

Because the path is searched before standard locations, you now have a shell with full root privileges, because it was started by a process with those privileges.

Sanitisisation prevents this hole from being exploited. Before SELinux, I believe the user/group ID and effective user/group ID was used to decide on whether sanitisation was warranted. SELinux introduced the concept of a flag that the kernel would set for a relevant security change.

---

It's the same reason you try to avoid putting `.` anywhere on the `root` user `PATH` variable. If that's done, there's the possibility that `root` will run some arbitrary user-created script with full power.

For example, if I create an `ls` script in my home directory, then inform the administrator that `ls` returns funny characters in the output, but only when the current directory is my home directory, the first thing they're likely to do is check it:

```sh
root$ cd /home/paxdiablo
root$ ls
```

If they foolishly had a path of `.:all/other/paths`, it's game over, man :-)

My `ls` script would do something like create a new user with the same power as `root` but with a password known to me, then run the real `ls` so as to convince admin-guy there's no issue. Admin-guy would then call me an idiot and close the ticket, but I would have got my back door into the system.